# Pumping Lemma Squares Proof Explanation

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm looking for some help understand this perfect squares proof using the pumping lemma.  Here is the proof:

[image: proof]

I don't understand how n^2 + k < n^2 + n towards the end of the proof.  Would anyone be able to explain this to me?  I also think that the last line n^2 < n^2+k < (n+1)^2 confusing because of (n^2 + k < n^2 + n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First from the statement of the pumping lemma we know that $|xy|\le n$. Also we have set $k$ to be the length of $y$, i.e. $|y|=k$. Moreover the length of $xy$ is certainly greater or equal than the length of $y$: $|xy|\ge |y|$. Combining these we get

$$n\ge |xy|\ge |y|=k$$

therefore $n^2+k\le n^2+n<n^2+2n+1=(n+1)(n+1)=(n+1)^2.$

Note that equality $k=n$ may occur if and only if $x$ is empty. Otherwise $k<n$.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped.  Would you be able to explain where the n^2+2n+1 comes from?

Comment: @user3130467: It comes from wanting to find the next square number after $n^2+n$. Certainly $n^2+n<n^2+2n+1$ is a true statement, since we can subtract $n^2+n$ on both sides and then we are left with $0<n+1$ which is true, since $n$ is a natural number. Now $n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$ by the binomial formula, so we determined that $n^2+n$ (and therefore also $n^2+k$) lies between two consecutive squares: between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I only recently got this privilege on the math area of stackexchange.  I have upvoted all of your posts and appreciate your help.